# Validar caracteres, mayúsculas, minúsculas y caracteres numéricos y otros, para una contraseña en C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

La expresión debe de cumplir lo siguiente:

1. Longitud (Min 8 - Max 15)
2. Debe contener mínimo un número
3. Debe contener un carácter especial de los siguientes: ñ Ñ - _ ¿ . # ¡
4. Debe contener una letra en mayúscula
5. No debe contener el nombre del usuario
6. No debe contener la identificación del usuario
7. No debe contener la palabra “admin” ni “contraseña”
8. No debe contener alguna de las secuencias numéricas, alfabéticas o de teclado 123, 12345, 56789, 123456789, 321, 54321, 987654321, 56789, qwerty, asdf , zxcv , poiuy , lkjhg,  mnbv.

Consultando, encontre el siguiente codigo en donde se validan las primeras 4 condiciones, pero no se como agregar las otras.

```js
^(?=(?:.*\d){1})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})\S{8,15}$
```

Según he consultado, debo usar `RegularExpressions` , se que la linea de código expuesta es la que indica las condiciones y que la sintaxis de las mismas son estos [caracteres](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), pero no se como agregar la condición de los numerales del 5 al 8, puedo agregar los caracteres ahí ? algo así:

```js
^(?=(?:.*\d){1})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*[ñÑ-_¿.#¡])(?=(?:.*[^"admin" "contraseña"]))\S{8,15}$
```

Comment: Hola @Jhohan, con todo el respeto tu pregunta me suena a me han mandado esto, podeis hacermelo?. Te recomiendo que intentes realizar cada apartado por separado. Para probar las expresiones regulares te recomiendo esta  [pagina](https://regexr.com) y para el apartado 8 por ejemplo que uses listas. Si aun asi tienes dudas en algun apartado en concreto no dudes en preguntarnos mostrando el codigo que has intentado hasta el momento!

Comment: hola jhohan como dice @capt.teach no hay problema por parte de la comunidad en ayudar si lo hay en hacer el trabajo de otro, al menos edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo que haz intentado hacer para poder ayudarte

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Yo tengo mis serias dudas de que una expresion regular sea la solucion a esto.. es mas.. si quisieras explicarle al usuario porque su contraseña fallo, no podrias...

Comment: @Capt.Teachque que pena, creo que no me supe expresar, lo que pasa es que apenas estoy consultando sobre el tema y no entiendo muy bien la sintaxis de las RegularExpressions, entonces estoy algo enredado, pero en ningún momento pedí eso, quiero aprender. (Ya la corregí, espero así no se presente este malentendido) no me den tanto palo, es segunda ves que publico acá jajajajaj

Comment: @gbianchi mmm pero el RegExp.test devuelve un bool si algo de esa cadena no cumplió, así se podría decir al usuario que el texto debe tener ciertos lineamientos

Comment: y con que devuelva un bool que solucionas? un if(password.contains(nombredelusuario) tambien devuelve un bool.. y ya validaste si contenia o no el nombre del usuario. ;)

Comment: mmm, genial, no sabia eso, creo que mejor usare eso que me dices, muchas gracias, has ayudado muchísimo publicalo como respuesta si quieres, para darle calificación (Creo que asi funciona esto, no?) :D

Comment: Si, asi funciona el sitio, dando una respuesta completa a una pregunta. Sin embargo, lo que te puse es un ejemplo y no soluciona todos tus problemas.. solo uno. Trabaja sobre eso, y si tenes otro problema edita tu pregunta y trabajamos sobre eso. Tambien es valido que soluciones tu propio problema y pongas tu propia respuesta ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta es mi propuesta para hacerlo de una manera "sencilla" y con la cual puedes indicarle al usuario donde ha fallado su contraseña.

Empezamos con los regex:

```
Match matchLongitud = Regex.Match(pass,@"^\w{8,15}\b");
Match matchNumeros = Regex.Match(pass,@"\d");
Match matchEspeciales = Regex.Match(pass,@"[ñÑ\-_¿.#¡]");
Match matchMayusculas = Regex.Match(pass,@"[A-Z]");
Match matchAdmin = Regex.Match(pass,@"admin");
Match matchContraseña = Regex.Match(pass,@"contraseña");
// MATCH con el valor de nombreUsuario
// MATCH con el valor de la identificacion del usuario
// Ahora creamos un Array de palabras prohibidas  :)
String[] palabrasProhibidas = {"123", "12345", "56789", "123456789", "321", "54321", "987654321", "56789", "qwerty", "asdf" ,"zxcv" , "poiuy" , "lkjhg"," mnbv"};
```

Lo siguiente sera crear 2 variables que nos indicaran si la contraseña introducia no ha cumplido los criterios de seguridad y el error asociado a dicho fallo para poder comunicarselo al usuario.

```
bool errorFlag = false;
int errorCode = 0;
```

Ahora empezamos a comprobar punto a punto la seguridad de la contraseña introducida:

```
if (!matchNumeros.Success) {

    errorCode=1;
    errorFlag=true;
} else if (errorFlag || !matchLongitud.Success) {

    errorCode=2;
    errorFlag=true;
}
```

Como ves comprobamos si el `match.Success` NO cumple el patron de seguridad, por lo que le asociamos un numero de error que luego usaremos para informar al usuario que ha fallado y un cambiamos el valor de nuesta bandera para que obviamente si ya ha habido error no siga comprobando los demas.

Lo siguiente sera mostrar si ha habido algun error o todo ha ido bien:

```
switch (errorCode){
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Ups! Tu contraseña debe de tener una longitud entre 8-15 caracteres");
        break;
    case 2:
         Console.WriteLine("Ups! Tu contraseña debe  contener mínimo un número");
        break;
    default:
         Console.WriteLine("La contraseña cumple con las normas de seguridad");
        break;
}
```

Gracias a los valores de `errorCode` sabremos si ha habido o no algun fallo ( te recomiendo cambiar el default y poner algun error generico)

Por ultimo te dejo una pista de como hacer para compara tu contraseña con el array de `palabrasProhibidas`

```
for (int i = 0; i < palabrasProhibidas.Length; i++)
    {
        Match Match = Regex.Match(pass, palabrasProhibidas[i]);
        if (Match.Success)
        {
           // errorCode = X


        }
    }
```

Este codigo es orientativo no significa que este bien, pero espero que te ayude a empezar cualquier cosa la comunidad de StackOverflowES estaremos dispuesto a ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias, realmente desenredas mucho mi enredo, en cuanto a la validacion de las palabras Prohibidas, lo hice con una lista y con un foreach. cual es mejor ?

Comment: @JhohanDavid si recorrer la lista con un foreach resuelve tu problema pues es una solucion valida! . SI mi respuesta soluciona el problema de tu pregunta no olvides de votar mi respuesta y marcarla como aceptada :)

Comment: Cuando valido una clave para que cumpla esto, sale error System.StackOverflowException, sabes a que se debe de casualidad ?

Comment: En que parte te da el error? en el bucle? Si ves que te va a costar expplicarlo siempre puedes crear una nueva pregunta

Comment: ya hice una pregunta nueva  [Error StackOverflowExeption](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271628/system-stackoverflowexception-en-validacion-de-clave) ahi puse toda la info.