# System.StackOverFlowException en validacion de clave

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito crear una clave que cumpla con unas características especificas, para ello tengo el siguiente código,

```
public static string CrearPassword(int longitud)
    {
        string caracteres = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzA1ñÑ-_¿.#¡";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < longitud--)
        {
            res.Append(caracteres[rnd.Next(caracteres.Length)]);
        }

        while (ValidPassword(res.ToString())== false)
        { 
            return CrearPassword(13);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }
```

el cual genera o crea una clave aleatoria y luego valida que cumpla con ciertos criterios de seguridad por medio del método del siguiente código.

```
public static bool ValidPassword(string pass)
    {
        Match matchLongitud = Regex.Match(pass, @"^\w{8,15}\b");
        Match matchNumeros = Regex.Match(pass, @"\d{1,15}");
        Match matchEspeciales = Regex.Match(pass, @"[ñÑ\-_¿.#¡]{1,2}");
        Match matchMayusculas = Regex.Match(pass, @"[A-Z]{1}");
        Match matchAdmin = Regex.Match(pass, @"admin");
        Match matchContraseña = Regex.Match(pass, @"contraseña");
        var valoresProhibidos = new List<string>() { "123", "12345", "56789", "123456789", "321", "54321", "987654321", "qwerty", "asdf", "zxcv", "poiuy", "lkjhg", "mnbv" };

        if (matchNumeros.Success)
            return false;
        else if (matchLongitud.Success)
            return false;
        else if (matchEspeciales.Success)
            return false;
        else if (matchMayusculas.Success)
            return false;
        else if (!matchAdmin.Success)
            return false;
        else if (!matchContraseña.Success)
            return false;
        else { 
            foreach (string valor in valoresProhibidos)
            {
                if (pass.Contains(valor))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

cuando lo ejecuto y hago paso a paso, el entra varias veces, y todo bien, pero cuando le coy continuar, sale siempre en una linea diferente el error StackOverFlowException y no entiendo por que ocurre, espero puedan ayudarme.

[image: Error]

Comment: Intento reproducir tu código y al parecer está mal en ValidPassword ya que no todas las rutas devuelven un valor. Ponlo completo, por favor.

Comment: al final del ValidPassword, por el return que se me olvido ponerlo en la publicacion `return true;`

Answer (score 0):

Después de revisar tu código, la excepción se da debido a que nunca se pasa el test correspondiente a las siguientes dos líneas:

```
Match matchAdmin = Regex.Match(pass, @"admin");
Match matchContraseña = Regex.Match(pass, @"contraseña");
```

Siempre son false y se van realizando llamadas recursivas debido a este ciclo:

```
while (ValidPassword(res.ToString()) == false)
{
    return CrearPassword(13);
}
```

Por lo tanto, se desborda la memoria por muchas llamadas anidadas a un mismo método

Revisa [StackOverflowException Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) para más información.

Comment: lo que pasa es que necesito crear una contraseña que cumpla esos parámetros, y lo que se me ocurrió fue ese ciclo por eso es que lo llama tantas veces, ese error no sale siempre, como puedo, hacerlo para que no salga ese error ?

Comment: ¿Quieres crear una función que genere una contraseña "random" que cumpla todos esos parámetros? Entonces crea una nueva pregunta y lo vemos. El tema en esta pregunta era la excepción y el por qué sucede. No olvides votar las respuestas, así es como la comunidad se fortalece. Saludos.

Comment: ya la cree (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271957/como-crear-una-contrase%C3%B1a-ramdom-y-que-cumpla-con-unos-caracteres-especificos)