# Como crear una contraseña ramdom y que cumpla con unos caracteres especificos

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito crear una Contraseña random pero que cumpla con unos parámetros específicos :

Debe tener una mayus

Debe tener numeros

Debe tener caracteres especiales.

No puede contener las siguientes cadenas "123", "12345", "56789", "123456789", "321", "54321", "987654321", "qwerty", "asdf", "zxcv", "poiuy", "lkjhg", "mnbv"

Entre otras.

ya lo hice con el siguiente código, pero me arroja un error de StackOberflowException, de que otra forma lo puedo lograr o cual seria la solución a este error ?

```
public static string CrearPassword(int longitud,string usuario)
    {
        string caracteres = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ñÑ-_¿.#¡";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < longitud--)
        {
            res.Append(caracteres[rnd.Next(caracteres.Length)]);
        }

        while (ValidPassword(res.ToString(), usuario)== false)
        { 
            return CrearPassword(13,usuario);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }

    public static bool ValidPassword(string pass, string usuario)
    {
        try
        {
            Match matchLongitud = Regex.Match(pass, @"^\w{8,15}\b");
            Match matchNumeros = Regex.Match(pass, @"\d");
            Match matchEspeciales = Regex.Match(pass, @"[ñÑ\-_¿.#¡]");
            Match matchMayusculas = Regex.Match(pass, @"[A-Z]");
            Match matchAdmin = Regex.Match(pass, @"admin");
            Match matchContraseña = Regex.Match(pass, @"contraseña");
            Match matchNombreUsuario = Regex.Match(pass, usuario);
            var valoresProhibidos = new List<string>() { "123", "12345", "56789", "123456789", "321", "54321", "987654321", "qwerty", "asdf", "zxcv", "poiuy", "lkjhg", "mnbv" };

            if (!matchNumeros.Success)
                return false;
            else if (!matchLongitud.Success)
                return false;
            else if (!matchEspeciales.Success)
                return false;
            else if (!matchMayusculas.Success)
                return false;
            else if (matchAdmin.Success)
                return false;
            else if (matchContraseña.Success)
                return false;
            else if (matchNombreUsuario.Success)
                return false;
            else
            {
                foreach (string valor in valoresProhibidos)
                {
                    if (pass.Contains(valor))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
```

el error que sale siempre es en una de estas lineas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
de antemano, gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El desbordamiento de la pila se debe a que tenia una ciclo que no siempre era infinito.

```
while (ValidPassword(res.ToString(), usuario)== false)
    { 
        return CrearPassword(13,usuario);
    }
    return res.ToString();
```

pero aveces si ocasionaba el error, en otras palabras, cuando no encontraba una contraseña valida no se detenía.

La solución consiste en crear otro método, el cual consume los dos que están en la pregunta, de esta manera.

```
public static string CreateValidPassword(int longitud, string usuario)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var password = CreateRandomPassword(longitud);
            if (ValidPassword(password,usuario))
                return password;
        }
    }
```

y eliminar primer ciclo que muestro en esta respuesta; 
Con esto al parecer se soluciono el problema, digo al parecer por que ya hice buena cantidad de pruebas, y pues ya no sale el error. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Tu error debe estar en este bloque de código:

```
while (0 < longitud--)
        {
            res.Append(caracteres[rnd.Next(caracteres.Length)]);
        }
```

En el while, tu código dice que:

> mientras 0< longitud-1

haga código... pongamos un ejemplo, si `longitud` vale  7:

> mientras 0 sea menor que longitud-1 (osea, 6), hacer:

entonces `longitud--` **siempre será 6.**

Corrígelo de la siguiente manera:

```
while (0 < longitud)
        {
            res.Append(caracteres[rnd.Next(caracteres.Length)]);
            longitud--;
        }
```

Comment: no funciono, sigue saliendo el mismo error en los `Match`

Comment: no mencionaste que el error salía en los `Match`, puedes especificar en qué linea exactamente y qué error? el error que muestras, es un `ovewflowException`, ese indica que tu aplicación se cicló y desbordó en el uso de memoria, no veo que tendría que ver eso con los `Match`

Comment: ya la actualice.